# Influence of a qualitative variable on the correlation between two quantitative variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, linear, continuous-data

I have a dataset composed of 3 variables for 100 individuals. Two variables (A and B) are quantitative continuous variables and we think there's a linear correlation between them. The third one (C) is a catergorical one with three levels (1,2,3). I want to know if the strength of the correlation between A and B is influenced by the level of C, e.g. Is the correlation between A and B stronger/weaker when belongings to C1?

Is a linear model informative in that case? Or should I compare correlation coefficient for each variables through Fisher Z transformations?